# Do you need to use session_unset before session_destroy?

Tags: php, session

According to w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to remove a session (log out) you should do it this way:

```
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
```

But I don't understand why you'd have to unset all session variables first, wouldn't just `session_destroy` be enough?

Comment: Keep in mind, not all sessions are to check if the user is logged in or not - using `session_destroy()` or the likes, will destroy **all** of them. To log out, you might want to `unset($_SESSION['name']);` instead - to preserve the (possibly) remaining sessions unrelated to signing in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the following information on the official documentation (https://php.net) about `session_destroy`:

> It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.
>   **source:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

And the documentation of `session_unset` says the following:

> The `session_unset()` function frees all session variables currently registered.
>   **source:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

So with these informations you have to call the following to clear a session completely:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

---

**You don't want to clear the whole session?**

In case your are using a system to login and logout a user, you can also remove specific fields of the session using `unset`:

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['other_user_data']);
```

In this case you only remove data of the user and not data for other parts of your application not related to the user.